# How to map a path variable to an entity in spring-rest

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I got some REST endpoint in Spring-RS which use an entity id as path variable. Most of the time, the first thing the method is doing is retrieving the entity using the id. Is there a way to automatically map the id to the entity, having only the entity as methods parameters ?

Current situation :

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{entityId})
public void method(@PathVariable String entityId) {
    Entity entity = entityRepository.findOne(entityId);
    //Do some work
}
```

What I would like to have :

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{entityId})
public void method(@PathVariable Entity entityId) {
    //Do some work
}
```

Comment: `@RequestMapping(path="/{entityId})
public void method(@PathVariable String entityId) {
    Entity e = new Entity(entityId); 
}`

You can't map a PathVar to an entity, BUT you can put part or all of you entity into the payload of you rest request.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible if you are using Spring Data. See [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#core.web.basic)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doctor/appointments/{start}/{end}", produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public List<Appointment> showAppointments(Model model, @ModelAttribute("start") Date start,
        @ModelAttribute("end") Date end, Principal principal) {

}
```

to get your custom object and Spring will try to convert the parameter to the given type.

I prefer to pass the id most of the times for security reasons.

Comment: The problem here is that I want the entity created by a request to database, not only from the data provided by the client